# Potential for particle rolling down slope of arbitrary shape

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity

I've been thinking about how to calculate the potential $V(x)$ of a particle rolling under the force of gravity down some curve, given by $f(x)$ (suppose nonincreasing). My idea was to simply calculate the force, and then integrate, using $-dV/dx=F(x)$.

First of all, I looked at the simplest example which would be the regular inclined plane with angle $\theta$. The problem I immediately encountered is that the motion is one dimensional, the "experiment" itself is two dimensional, and the force is a vector quantity directed along the inclined plane, along the direction of motion (supposing regular coordinate system), the versor $\hat{v} \equiv (\cos \theta, -\sin \theta)$:

$$ {\bf F} =  mg\sin \theta \ \hat{v} $$

But to use the formula, this needs to be expressed in terms of the one coordinate, which I would take to be the length $q$ measured from the top of the inclined plane along $\hat{v}$, then I can simply write

$$F(q)=mg\sin\theta,$$

and so $$V(q)=-mgq\sin\theta.$$

Now, can one re-express this in terms of $x$? Does it even make sense to do so..? In the case of an arbitrary curve $f(x)$, the force is one again the same, only now $\theta$ is variable and depends on $f'(x)$, but then $x$ would have to be expressed in terms of $q$, some generalized coordinate describing the motion (or does it need to be the length travelled along the curve?), which in general would produce incredibly complicated integrals..?

Even in the simplest case of a particle sliding along an $f(x)=x^2$ shaped incline, I don't know how to solve this nicely, the force would be

$$F(q)= mg \frac{f'(x(q))}{\sqrt{1-f'(x(q))}} = mg \frac{2x(q)}{\sqrt{1-2x(q)}}$$

With $q$ being the natural parametrisation, i.e. length from beginning of the curve, which is a very complicated function of $x$ already.

Is my analysis correct? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: The potential is just $mgh$, which if I understand your meaning correctly is just $mgf(x)$.

Comment: Hm, that's definitely embarrassing, but then how to understand the formula $F = -dV/dx$ ? After all the net force is not directed straight down, but along the incline

Comment: That's a vector equation ${\bf F} = -\nabla V$. What you've written is just the $x$ component $F_x = -dV/dx$.

Comment: But in the case of a one degree of freedom system, I don't understand the need for a vector equation. After all, isn't the motion along an inclined plane pretty much the same as free fall under 'weaker gravity' (by a factor of $\sin \theta$), from the point of view of the particle?

Comment: It's not a one degree of freedom system. You're moving in the $xy$ plane so there are two degrees of freedom. Your two equations of motion are $\ddot{x} = F_x/m$ and $\ddot{y} = F_y/m$.

Comment: I don't understand. The pendulum also moves in the $xy$ plane but is a one degree of freedom system, right? I'm assuming that the particle is fixed to move along the curve, perhaps I didn't state that clearly.

Comment: Ah OK, I see what you mean. If you can write your curve parametrically, i.e. instead of $y = f(x)$ use $y = y(\tau)$ and $x = x(\tau)$ for some parameter $\tau$, then yes it has one degree of freedom i.e. $\tau$. This is easy for the pendulum because you can use the angle to the vertical as the single parameter. But I'm not sure this is the best approach in general.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** The potential energy is $mgf(x)$

**Longer Answer:** Let's orient our coordinate system such that the force of gravity is in the $-y$ direction. It's simple to show the potential energy for a particle in this gravitational field is $mgy$. If we confine the particle to some curve $y = f(x)$, then the potential energy is $mgf(x)$.

The key point here is that there is an additional force of constraint that keeps the mass on the curve. For a pendulum, the force of constraint is tension and for a inclined plane, the force of constraint is the normal force. Without this force of constraint, the mass would just fall right off the curve.

Comment: Please explain why this is not true: $-dV/dq = F(q)$ where $q$ is the position along the curve.

Comment: What force are you talking about? $-dV/dq$ does equal $m\frac{d^2q}{dt^2}$

Comment: If you're looking for a rigorous formalism that discusses the motion of constrained motion, I would look up the Lagrangian Formalism, which I think is appropriate for you problem. It can get very mathematically complex, though.

Comment: Yes but the force along the curve is given by $mg \sin \theta$ with $\sin\theta$ as written in my original question. Are you saying that after expressing this force as a function of $q$, integrating to get $V(q)$ and then changing variables to $x$, I will recover $V(x)=mgf(x)$?

Comment: Take a line of slope $\tan\theta$ for example. The magnitude force is $mg\sin\theta$, then the potential energy is $mgq\sin\theta$. $f(x)=\tan\theta\cdot x$. $x$ just equals $q\cos\theta$. The potential energy is then $mgx\sin\theta\sec\theta$ which equals $mg\tan\theta=mgf(x)$. So yes, you will recover $V(x)$

Comment: Thank you. How to prove this for arbitrary $f$..? Should I make a seperate question asking this?

Comment: @DepeHb in the general case, how do you want to deal with the situation where the ball is moving fast enough to leave the curve (e.g. think about rolling down a convex half cylinder). Is the path a tube, so that the $y$-component of the normal force will point downward to keep the ball on the track? Or will it fly off the track?

Comment: @KyleOman I want to keep this one dimensional, so yes, this can be a ball inside a tube, or a bead sliding down a wire, no way to get off-track

Comment: @DepeHb a proof for arbitrary $f$ would be trivial using the Lagrangian Formalism, but quite nasty proved directly from Newton's Laws

Comment: Can you demonstrate it using the former?